What is a valid 4-layer stackup for a power mosfet driver board?
I'm creating a device intended to be used to test power circuit topologies without the need to create the auxiliary gate driver circuitry. This is accomplished by the mosfets gate being driven by a PWM signal being generated by a microcontroller. Additionally the device can be controlled via USB.
The layer stackup I had in mind was the following:
Layer 1: Signal (Top) — Primary signal routing for microcontroller and low-power signal traces
Layer 2: Ground (GND) — Solid ground plane for signal integrity and noise reduction
Layer 3: Power (VCC) — Power distribution for both the microcontroller and power electronics
Layer 4: Signal/Power (Bottom) — High-current traces and less critical signals, or split between power and signal sections
Would this be an appropiate stackup for my application?

What speed and capacity (peak current or resistance; drive power) of gate driver? What range of MOSFET type? How modular will this be, is the driver isolated? What do you mean by "topologies" plural, is there a manner in which MOSFETs can be reconfigured? What effect will this have on the switch loop stray inductance?  Thinking about board stackup at this point (with the above undefined), is almost certainly the wrong question (any will do, none will do, strict layer assignments not applicable, etc.).

Also, the title seems out of sync with the text: a valid stackup is pretty much anything. There exists, some application that, given a similarly undefined layout (assumed: any choice is valid), any stackup will do. Including no PCB at all (e.g. point-to-point wired).

Possibly. Stuff like controlled impedance traces and signals that dislike vias are non-negotiable and take priority. Since it's a power application, it makes sense to lay out your high current power and ground traces separately, even on the external layers for higher power handling capability. Traces for things like gate drive and the return path should be laid out separately as well, instead of trusting to the ground plane. Things like unintentional slot antennas or circuitous current paths in the ground plane should be identified and avoided.
If you give us more specifics, we can give you better answers.
